# Clear content of cell with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, cell

I want to dynamically change the content of the cells of an entire column. Currently I loop over the rows and append my element.

```
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
            var cell = row.cells[1];
            cell.appendChild(element.cloneNode(true))
```

This works fine. But the problem is, if I call this function again, an additional child is added. So each time I call the function an element is added. Is there a way to clear the content of the cell before I append my element or a way to update the content of the cell?

Comment: Yes, that is part of an html

Comment: Try `cell.innerHTML=element.cloneNode(true);` This will replace the content of the cell.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
while (cell.hasChildNodes()) {
    cell.removeChild(cell.lastChild);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
            var cell = row.cells[1];
            cell.innerHTML="";
            cell.appendChild(element.cloneNode(true))
```